# AdMob in Canvas

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, admob

So, i have separated class for drawing , and i want to draw there adMob , I call it from game class and pass activity as parameter :

```
public void drawAddMob(Activity a){
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(a);
ll.setPadding(0, 50, 0, 0);
adView = new AdView(a, AdSize.BANNER,  "a15140cd49b6e7b");  
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(request);
adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

ll.addView(adView);

ll.draw(canvas);
}
```

but when i do this i get error:

```
03-21 23:35:09.646: W/System.err(333):
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler 
inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-21 23:35:09.656: W/System.err(333):
at com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView.<init>  (SourceFile:69)
```

Comment: You need to run that code on the UI thread.

Comment: how can i catch UI thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this code on the UI thread, since it alters your UI. Try the following for your method body:

```
a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(a);
        ll.setPadding(0, 50, 0, 0);
        adView = new AdView(a, AdSize.BANNER,  "a15140cd49b6e7b");  
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(request);
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ll.addView(adView);

        ll.draw(canvas);
    }
});
```